# Save imap mails to a pop account

Tags: outlook, save, imap, pop3

Is there a solution where I can store my IMAP mails so I can transfer the imap emails to a pop3 account ?

Im using Outlook at the moment.

The problem is that my mail provider cant switch to pop3 witout deleting my emails :(

Comment: Why do you want to change from imap to pop3?!

Answer (score 0):

POP3 doesn't include an upload function, so no.  Unless you *also* have IMAP access, with which you could copy/upload the messages with.

Comment: I have now been told that you can add a extra account in outlook and then you can copy the imap mails over to the pop 3 account.

Comment: I still doubt that will upload them to the server.  They may just be sitting locally.